# error when creating an android projects in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

When creating an android project in unity there is always these 3 errors that doesn't make it compile without even adding anything.

1. > C:\ProgramFiles\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.0f1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.ugui\Runtime\EventSystem\InputModules\BaseInput.cs(19,24):
   >   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IMECompositionMode' could
   >   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
   >   reference?)
2. > C:\ProgramFiles\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.0f1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.ugui\Runtime\EventSystem\InputModules\BaseInput.cs(104,24): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Touch' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3. > C:\ProgramFiles\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.0f1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.ugui\Runtime\EventSystem\InputModules\PointerInputModule.cs(70,61): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Touch' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The errors are self explanatory, your project cannot find 2 files: touch and IMECompositionMode

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the same error as in this post: https://forum.unity.com/threads/i-have-a-problem-getting-start-in-webgl.736436/

This was for a WebGL build but if you follow the link in the sixth post (changing the version number) there's a download for Android as well.

> In my case I has installed WebGL Target Support for Unity 2019.1.1
>   (which I used for an older project), but my current project was on
>   2019.2.1. So go to https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/2019.2.1 (replace the last part of the url with whichever Unity version you're
>   using) and scroll down to WebGL Target Support and download+install it
>   (choose the correct Unity path in installation). That should fix the
>   problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the **Package Manager** from Unity (by some reason) is missing those files, and therefore cannot find them.

You could try:

- Reset the packages to default values (go to **Help** -> **Reset Package to Defaults**)
- Another thing that you could check, but only if you are using [Assembly Definitions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html) (.asmdef files), in this case, you should check if the dependencies are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the android build support module on your current unity version ? I had the same errors once and I realised this was the reason...